# I want to get the reversal of a 8-bit binary number and 1's complement of that reversal as a single output

Tags: assembly, emu8086

I have written this code, but I only get the reversed string as output. I want the 1's complement of the reversed string too as output. 
I know how can I get this. When I edit my code and make it ready for 1's complement of reversed string, my reversed string is no more!

**Test case:**

> input: 11010110

### output(that is needed):

> Reversed string: 01101011
>   1's Complement of it: 10010100

My code:

```
;REVERSING 8-BIT BINARY NO.

.MODEL
.STACK 100H
.DATA
    STR  DB 'Enter the binary number (max 8-bit) : $'
    STR2  DB 0DH,0AH,'REVERSED STRING : $'
    STR3 DB 'THE 1S COMPLEMENT OF IT: $'

.CODE
    MAIN PROC
    MOV AX, @DATA                  
    MOV DS, AX

    LEA DX, STR                  ; display STR   
    MOV AH, 9
    INT 21H


    XOR BL, BL                       ; CLEAR BL 
    MOV CX, 8                        ; loop for 8 times
    MOV AH, 1                        

    INPUT:                           
        INT 21H                      
        CMP AL, 0DH                  ; compare digit with carriage return (ENTER) 
        JZ END                       ; jump to END, if carriage return (JUMP IF ZERO)
        AND AL, 01H                  ; convert ascii to decimal code
        SHL BL, 1                    ; rotate BX to left by 1 bit
        OR BL, AL                    ; set the LSB of BX with input
        LOOP INPUT                   ; jump to INPUT

    END:                             
        MOV AL, BL                   ; copy BL into AL
        MOV CX, 8                    ; loop for 8 times

    LP:                              ; loop
        SHL AL, 1                    ; shift AL to left by 1 bit
        RCR BL, 1                    ; rotate BL right through carry
        LOOP LP                      ; jump to LP

    LEA DX, STR2                     ; load and display STR2   
    MOV AH, 9
    INT 21H

    MOV CX, 8                       
    MOV AH, 2                       ; output function


    OUTPUT:
      SHL BL, 1                     ; shift left BL by 1 bit
      JNC ZERO                      ; jump to label ZERO if CF=0
      MOV DL, 31H                   ; set DL=1. DL=0 for 1's compelement.
      JMP DISPLAY                   ; jump to DISPLAY

     ZERO:                        
       MOV DL, 30H                 ; set DL=0. DL=1 for 1's complement.

     DISPLAY:                     
       INT 21H                     ; display digit

     LOOP OUTPUT                   ; output


     MOV AH, 4CH                   
     INT 21H
   MAIN ENDP
 END MAIN
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ROL` instead of `SHL` on line 52 to keep the reversed value in `BL` register. Now you can reuse it later to output the 1's complement value like this:

```
    MOV CX, 8         ; For looping 8 times                      
    MOV AH, 2

_OUTPUT_INVERSE:
    ROL BL, 1         ; Rotate left by 1 bit
    JC  _I_ZERO       ; jump to label ZERO if CF=1
    MOV DL, 31H       ; set DL=1. DL=0 for 1's compelement.
    JMP _I_DISPLAY    ; jump to DISPLAY

_I_ZERO:                        
    MOV DL, 30H      ; set DL=0. DL=1 for 1's complement.

_I_DISPLAY:                     
    INT 21H

    LOOP _OUTPUT_INVERSE ; output the inverse
```

It works because after you have printed the reverse value, the `BL` register contains
the `6B` (ie. `01101011`). So, just shifting (or, rotating) the value left by one time
on each loop will give use the inverse value one by one, which is printed as before with
the reverse value.

**Full code:** (using your style)

```
;REVERSING 8-BIT BINARY NO.

.MODEL
.STACK 100H
.DATA
    STR  DB 'Enter the binary number (max 8-bit) : $'
    STR2 DB 0DH,0AH,'REVERSED STRING : $'
    STR3 DB 0DH,0AH,'THE 1S COMPLEMENT OF IT: $'

.CODE
    MAIN PROC
    MOV AX, @DATA                  
    MOV DS, AX

    LEA DX, STR         ; display STR   
    MOV AH, 9
    INT 21H


    XOR BL, BL          ; CLEAR BL 
    MOV CX, 8           ; loop for 8 times
    MOV AH, 1                        

    INPUT:                           
        INT 21H                      
        CMP AL, 0DH     ; compare digit with carriage return (ENTER) 
        JZ END          ; jump to END, if carriage return (JUMP IF ZERO)
        AND AL, 01H     ; convert ascii to decimal code
        SHL BL, 1       ; rotate BX to left by 1 bit
        OR BL, AL       ; set the LSB of BX with input
    LOOP INPUT          ; loop INPUT

    END:                             
        MOV AL, BL      ; copy BL into AL
        MOV CX, 8       ; loop for 8 times

    LP:                 ; loop
        SHL AL, 1       ; shift AL to left by 1 bit
        RCR BL, 1       ; rotate BL right through carry
    LOOP LP             ; jump to LP

    LEA DX, STR2        ; load and display STR2   
    MOV AH, 9
    INT 21H


    MOV CX, 8                       
    MOV AH, 2           ; output function


    OUTPUT_REVERSE:
      ROL BL, 1         ; rotate left BL by 1 bit
      JNC ZERO          ; jump to label ZERO if CF=0
      MOV DL, 31H       ; set DL=1. DL=0 for reversing the value.
      JMP DISPLAY       ; jump to DISPLAY

    ZERO:                        
      MOV DL, 30H       ; set DL=0. DL=1 for reversing the value.

    DISPLAY:                     
      INT 21H           ; display digit

    LOOP OUTPUT_REVERSE ; output reverse value

    LEA DX, STR3        ; load and display STR3   
    MOV AH, 9
    INT 21H


    MOV CX, 8                       
    MOV AH, 2           ; output function

    OUTPUT_INVERSE:
      ROL BL, 1         ; rotate left by 1 bit
      JC I_ZERO         ; jump to label ZERO if CF=1
      MOV DL, 31H       ; set DL=1. DL=0 for 1's compelement.
      JMP I_DISPLAY     ; jump to DISPLAY

    I_ZERO:                        
      MOV DL, 30H      ; set DL=0. DL=1 for 1's complement.

    I_DISPLAY:                     
      INT 21H

    LOOP OUTPUT_INVERSE ; output the inverse value 

    MOV AH, 4CH                   
    INT 21H
   MAIN ENDP
 END MAIN
```

**Output:**

```
Enter the binary number (max 8-bit) : 11010110
REVERSED STRING : 01101011
THE 1S COMPLEMENT OF IT: 10010100
```

By the way, you don't need lines 26 and 27 since the loop is running only 8 times.

Comment: @UtshabKumarGhosh:  You can simplify this by reading CF with `adc dl, 0`.  e.g. `mov dl, '0'` / `rol bl,1` / `adc dl,0` then print, no branching required.

Comment: Similarly, you can shift the low bit from AL into the bottom of BL with `shr al,1` / `adc bl,bl` in your `input` loop.

Comment: (`adc same,same` is a more efficient way to do `rcl reg,1` on most CPUs.  RCL by 1 is only useful for memory operands on modern x86, or if the different flag setting of RCL is actually useful.  Their flag *input* behaviour is identical)

Comment: Why don't you `call` that output loop and `call` it again for the one's complement? `LEA DX, STR2` `call Output` `not bl` `LEA DX, STR3` `call Output`